# How can I improve my code to handle large numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, runtime, mergesort

I am doing a hackerrank challenge for counting the inversions but I am unable to pass few test cases as it says timeout. I run the test cases on my system and it takes around 10 sec to get the correct result.

Here is the code:

```
def merge_sort_inversion(listA):
  n=len(listA)
  if n==1 or n==0:
    return listA,0

  left_subArray=listA[:n/2]
  right_subArray=listA[n/2:]

  left_subArray, left_inversion=merge_sort_inversion(left_subArray)
  right_subArray,right_inversion=merge_sort_inversion(right_subArray)
  sorted_list, split_inversion=merge_inversion(left_subArray,right_subArray)


  return sorted_list,left_inversion+right_inversion+split_inversion
#sorted_list=[]
def merge_inversion(left,right):
  sorted_list=[]
  count=0
  if len(left)==0 or len(right)==0:
    return left+right,0

  i=0
  j=0
  for k in range(len(left)+len(right)):
    if len(left)!=i and len(right)!=j:
      if left[i]>right[j]:
        sorted_list.append(right[j])
        count=count+len(left[i:])
        #print right[j], left[i:],count
        j=j+1
      else:
        sorted_list.append(left[i])
        i=i+1
    elif len(left)==i:
      return sorted_list+right[j:],count
    elif len(right)==j:
      return sorted_list+left[i:],count
  return sorted_list,count

t = int(raw_input().strip())
for a0 in xrange(t):
    n = int(raw_input().strip())
    arr = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    a,b=merge_sort_inversion(arr)
    print b
```

Can someone please advise?

Comment: the input consists of 100000 numbers

Comment: What do you mean with counting the inversions?

Comment: Is this an active challenge?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I think this is a general challenge. anyone can login to hackerrank and try solve any time. [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort/problem)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Here is the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is very slow:

```
count=count+len(left[i:])
```

because it generates a new list from all elements of left from position i upwards.

As you only need the resulting length, you can do this much faster via:

```
count += len(left) - i
```

On my computer this reduces the time for an array with 100,000 elements from 7.5 seconds to 0.5 seconds.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks!
 I guess len(left[i:]) is slow as it has to generate left[i:] first ?

Comment: Yes, left[i:] is defined to be a new array with a copy of the given elements.